# Differences between standard keyboard layout in windows and linux?

Tags: 12.04, windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm want to switch from using mostly osx to using mostly linux (for everything unix) and windows (unfortunately, because of work, I need to be effective using excel/outlook and various other apps in the "native" enviroment, wine won't do) in vms. Now, I know there are differences in the keyboard layout of osx and linux (@ key, ' key etc. etc.), but does ubuntu and windows have the same keyboard layout? (My goal is to be able to use ubuntu 90% of the time and seamlessly switch into windows when I have to.) If there are any differences, what are they? And is it possible to make linux use the same keyboard layout as windows?

Answer (score 1):

Go "system settings -> Keyboard Layout" then click the "+" button. I am guessing the difference your experiencing is the difference between US and UK keyboard if you are using English, so choose the one that isn't currently active (look at the layout preview if you want to check) and then you can delete your original layout from the list with the "-" button.